# Need to Pivot String values in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have table with values, described as:

| Occupation String | Name String |
| --- | --- |
| Developer | A |
| Developer | B |
| Designer | X |
| Coder | Y |
| Coder | Z |

I need values in pivot format as:

| Designer | Developer | Coder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | Y |
| Null | B | Z |

Can anyone help on this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does your data know, that Y is bound to X and A while Z is bound to B and does not have a Designer?

Comment: I would guess you want to use a row number function to order the values (partitioned by the operation string) then pivot the results...

Comment: That relation is not there.. data is just sorted alphabeticaly.. after pivot

Comment: This design is - uhm - weak... Your table does not have any implicit order. The relation between your values will be near to random (at least unpredictable...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic PIVOT with ROW_NUMBER() will do things for you:

```
SELECT  [Developer],
        [Designer],
        [Coder]
FROM (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM #temp
) as t
PIVOT (
    MAX(Name) FOR Occupation IN ([Developer],[Designer],[Coder])
) as pvt
```

Output:

```
Developer   Designer    Coder
A           X           Y
B           NULL        Z
```

If the number of `Occupation`s may vary then you need dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @columns = (
    SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME(Occupation)
    FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT  '+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+'
FROM (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM #temp
) as t
PIVOT (
    MAX(Name) FOR Occupation IN ('+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+')
) as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**Note:** I have used `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` just to get some random ordering. Better use some actual field for this purpose.

Comment: Your `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` will define some order, but this is not predictable. I'd say, that this approach - even if it works! - is something one should not do...

Comment: @Shnugo instead of `(SELECT NULL)` OP can use ANY field he need/can. It is just an example. Personally I use such ordering if I don't have any field to do sort with and this is rare thing in our (company) DBs.

Comment: Thanks.. U r a savier ! I invested hours in it.. :(

Comment: Yes, but people don't know about this... You test this, it works, it works a hundred times and suddenly you get something else... As long as you **are aware of the fact, that the order you imply is unpredictable**, you might do this, but I would not...

Comment: My pleasure! As Shnugo commented, better use some other field instead of `(SELECT NULL)` that gives some random ordering.