# Why does pivoting of a string data column work with row_number?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, row-number

I had a problem where I need to pivot on a string column. I found the solution in the link below, but cannot understand why pivoting works for column with string data when row_number is used.

[Need to Pivot String values in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505190/need-to-pivot-string-values-in-sql-server)

Table definition:

```
ColumnName  DataType
----------  --------
Occupation  String 
Name        String
```

Data:

```
Occupation  Name
----------  ----
Developer    A
Developer    B
Designer     X
Coder        Y
Coder        Z
```

The query used was:

```
SELECT  [Developer],
        [Designer],
        [Coder]
FROM (
      SELECT  *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
              RN
      FROM 
           #temp
     ) as t
PIVOT 
    (
      MAX(Name) 
      FOR Occupation 
      IN ([Developer],[Designer],[Coder])
    ) as pvt
```

Output:

```
Developer   Designer    Coder
A           X           Y
B           NULL        Z
```

Comment: . . A question should be complete in itself.  This needs sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  A link to something that says "I don't understand" is not a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

In previous question the 'MAX' aggregation function was used. It returns only one row for table with two columns: one value for developer, one for coder et.c. Row_number function adds a dimension to the table and you get this:

```
Developer   Designer    Coder
A              X          Y
B             NULL        Z
```

instead of this:

```
Developer   Designer    Coder
B              X          Z
```

Comment: Still can't understand. Can you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @user9463 pivoting in SQL requires an aggregation function (sum, count, avg, max, min). Since we deal with string data, we can use only MAX and MIN functions. These functions return only one value for a column in pivot table if we have only two columns in input table. So the query returns only letters with maximal ASCII value for each job in this case (B, X and Z). We add a column with row numbers over each job  to separate subsets and apply aggregation function to each value instead of their subset. And we get pivot with multiple rows instead of pivot with one row